# Flexbox not working in safari (prefixed)

Tags: css, flexbox

For some reason, my flexbox is not working in Safari.

It is also not working for me in Chrome on iOS, however Chrome on my Mac or on Android devices works just fine. Below is my code.

```
div.row {
 padding: 0;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 -ms-flex-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 -ms-justify-content: center;
 }
div.inner {
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -webkit-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 10px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 min-width: 200px;
}
```

I made a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mynv6k4q/ to show.

When the viewport gets smaller, the block on the bottom is supposed to stretch out and the two blocks on top need to be alongside each other until they get a width less than 200px. This works fine in Chrome, but Safari won't work, even though it is prefixed.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Safari and on which OS?

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by changing "flex: 1" to "flex: 1 0 200px". Apparently min-width does not really work in combination with Flexbox in Safari.

Comment: This post really helped me out. I was able to get my DOM elements with flex properties to display properly using your suggestion some with media queries and/or changing the `flex` property from `flex: 1;` to `flex: 1 1 auto;`. I found that the default `flex` property is `flex: 0 1 auto;`, so I threw in the default values for troublesome elements and they worked correctly.